# uiwebview Video cannot be played in IOS 12.2

Tags: ios, uiwebview

iOS 12.2 real machine can not play the video in html5 loaded by UIWebView, link url http://community.cqliving.com/h5/info/detail/512.html?cid=512&isOpenApp=&f=10, other versions can play video

[Rendering](https://upload-images.jianshu.io/upload_images/3889208-d8bcf17c6ceb414d.png?imageMogr2/auto-orient/strip%7CimageView2/2/w/1240)

Comment: UIWebView was replaced by WKWebView back in iOS 8.

Comment: @maddy no it wasn't, UIWebView still exists today, and even now WKWebView doesn't have all of the functionality of UIWebView

Answer (score 4):

Try including these two lines

```
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

These lines solved my issue which is occurring in iOS 12.2

Comment: When i try to do this in swift i get "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Bool?"

Answer (score 2):

Is it embedded using UIWebView or WKWebView or similar?

Try setting `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` to `YES` for the webview. I'm seeing the same issue (`UIWebView` and `WKWebView` both) in iOS 12.2. Works fine in iOS 12.1 and earlier.

When debugging, you see this error in safari console:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not
>   allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context,
>   possibly because the user denied permission

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617954-mediaplaybackrequiresuseraction?language=objc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1614727-mediaplaybackrequiresuseraction?language=objc

Could be similar to this issue

[Video from local storage not playing in WebView (Xamarin.Forms) after latest iOS update (12.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615862/video-from-local-storage-not-playing-in-webview-xamarin-forms-after-latest-ios/55945418#55945418)

Answer (score 2):

mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
look：https://www.jianshu.com/p/d3f326dae445

Comment: Yes I think this is the same as what I had seen

Comment: When i try to do this in swift i get "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Bool?"

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable insecure content loading in your app. Otherwise if you would not like to do that you can create a mirror of the video on a secure server.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30732693 see here for more info.

Comment: Thank you ! http://community.cqliving.com/h5/info/detail/512.html?cid=512&isOpenApp=&f=10 The video in h5 webpage cannot be played. in IOS 12.2 Other version Can Played