# iOS 12.2/ Swift: Problem with reading videos on html in the UIWebView on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

I have an app that worked well with all versions, all devices and simulator lower than iOS 12.2.
Since that new version, it doesn't work on the iPhone with iOS 12.2 without any error message ( I don't see that message occuring: nhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: ).  I precise that it works on the simulator, on the ipad in iOS 12.2 but not the iphone.
I check that [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821523/uiwebview-video-cannot-be-played-in-ios-12-2) but it doesn't resolve the situation.

I added that fonctions to true with no success:

> ```
>     webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = true
>     webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
>     webView.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = true
> ```

I added that keys with no success:
[image]

```
   <div class="col-md-12"><p class="ttl">'+tab_bloctitre[1]+'</p><video   controls style="width:100%;" poster="'+key+'/img/fondvideo.png"><source src="'+tab_videobloc[1].replace("https://gmp2.newtelapps.fr/uploads/R1550158082/img/",lien)+'" type="video/mp4"></video></div>'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;
```

from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56074115/279180

If you don't want auto-play, make sure you don't have "autoplay" in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

indexWeb.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = NO;
This setup solves my problem。